# How to import a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently coding a Discord bot in JS with Node.js and I wanted to write the commands code in a file for each command. All of these files are in a commands folder. Here is my code : in index.js :

```
const help = require("./commands/help.js")
help.help()
```

and in help.js :

```
function help() {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#0099ff")
        .setTitle("Commandes du serveur")
        .addField("&help", "Commandes du bot")
        .addField("&youtube", "Lien vers la chaîne YouTube d'ANGI49")
        .addField("&twitch", "Lien vers la chaîne Twitch d'ANGI49")
        .setFooter("Bot développé par ANGI498045 et ywalt.js")

    message.reply({ embeds: [embed]});
}
module.exports()
```

The import never works and i have a module not found error
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For a CommonJS module that uses `require()` (there two different module types in nodejs), in help.js, change this:

```
module.exports()
```

to this:

```
module.exports.help = help;
```

Then, you should be able to do this:

```
const help = require("./commands/help.js")
help.help()
```

As long as the `"./commands/help.js"` path is correct.